# Why is the compilation of my (x86->64) windows cross compiler failing?

Tags: gcc, mingw, cross-compiling, x86-64

I'm trying to build a cross-compiler (x86->64) on my windows system, with the aim of targetting windows 64, however my software currently relies on open source libraries which also have open source dependencies for which there are no prebuilt binaries available with which I can compile. This means that if I want the 64 bit versions I need to compile them.

I've installed MSYS and mingw, I'm also in the process of adding mingw-w64 to the mix so that I can finally compile the libraries in 64 bit form for use with my software. I'm following the steps as closely as I can [using these instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Cross%20Win32%20and%20Win64%20compiler) and in the order listed on that page, I'm currently at the step titled "**Building the GCC core cross-compiler(s)**", but when I try to compile with the line:

> $ ../gcc-4.6.1/configure --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all && make -j 6 all-gcc && make -j 6 install-gcc

I get the [output pasted here](http://pastebin.com/8yV1YeJd). I should note that I of course snipped the previously executed commands and that last command was the last one listed before all the errors were displayed. Also, I have no idea if it's the cause of all the errors due to the '-j 6' argument, but everything prior to it at least *looked* successful.

**What's the problem and how can I fix it?**

Oh, in anticipation of one potential suggestion; no I can't just switch to cygwin.

**Edit**: Okay after executing them individually, [here's the output of the **configure** command](http://pastebin.com/UC917E7d), [the output produced by `make all-gcc` (no -j argument)](http://pastebin.com/hM13mBf6), and [**config.log**](http://pastebin.com/9pk8bExx). Note, I didn't run a `make clean` beforehand which may explain the different ending, I didn't do it in the interest of time to write this update, but I suppose I'll just make a different compile folder and re-execute it cleanly to hopefully see the same error as before while I wait for a response.

**Edit 2**: The `make all-gcc` failed again as expected, this time [the output](http://pastebin.com/MGSKGn7d) should help a little more I hope.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: After you get the error, run make again without the -j option to see exactly which command generates it. Looking at the errors, it seems as though the assembler is barfing on instructions it doesn't recognize, so your toolchain may not be ready to emit x64 code.

Comment: I've started the compilation process over as you suggested. What you say sort of makes sense.. but I find it rather odd because it seems to me that the whole purpose of this step is to compile the compiler which would be capable of doing exactly that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config.log` shows that the build process will use the binaries in x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin for stuff like ar, as etc... These are for internal compiler use only, and they should all be available in your /mingw/bin directory. I would strongly suggest asking on the mingw-w64-public mailing list for help.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of the first thing you said, but I have just signed up to the mailing list and sent off an e-mail. Thanks for your suggestion!